# Are there any special rules for charging sales tax in US Territories such as Puerto Rico?

Tags: united-states, sales-tax, puerto-rico

Are there any special rules for charging sales tax in US Territories such as [Puerto Rico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Rico)?

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start is [this link](http://www.export.gov/logistics/eg_main_018138.asp) at the US Department of Commerce.